# Webdriver IO How to store Excel file in cache and call from cache on Node JS

Tags: node.js, webdriver-io

I have an excel file that I want to only call in once and make available to all of my tests, at the moment it's being called on each test, I have tried storing it in the cache using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache but when I tried to get it from cache it's saying undefined, so then I tried using onPrepare hook with no luck. Can someone point me in the right direction thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to store the sheet in the browser cache? A better explanation of your use case could help in providing a solution/alternative way to your problem.

Comment: Yeah that would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that excel has data for test automation and it does not include any writing operations, I would suggest reading the content and store it in a constant. If you declare that variable globally, it will be available to all your tests. The complexity of this READ function depends on how diverse is your data. You can use libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx, https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs, etc..,